# Looking for PyQGIS Syntax Examples/Guide

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am a long-time user of arcgis with intermediate experience python scripting for automation of geoprocessing workflows. I am moving towards using QGIS on the regular and I would like to dive into python scripting for QGIS.  However, I have previously relied on esri's help screens which contain python syntax as well as examples ([ESRI Example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000)). Is there an equivalent of this python documentation for QGIS? I have found the [PyQgis Cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/index.html) limited and the [API Documentation](http://qgis.org/api/index.html) beyond what I'm able to undertake.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

thanks in advance,
mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the Cookbook and API documentation, the best source for working code is the working code ;)

Meaning: Look at existing plugins to see how they solve tasks. It's open source after all.

If you get stuck. Don't hesitate to ask specific questions here or on the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks, UD. I guess I'll start with sextante. If anyone has other suggestions as to appropriate plugins to get started with PyQGIS, I'm all ears... maybe mmqgis?